# Shortened properties in GE?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

For some of my properties, the numbers would sometimes read something like `0.1231231230938...`, which basically is absurd. Is there a way to duplicate this property and have it only read `x` numbers after the decimal? Thanks!

Comment: if this is for printing only you should be good with `print("%.2f" %myProp)`

Comment: @Chebhou is there a way to have that in a property? Something like own['smallprop'] = ".2f" %largeprop? (Assuming we already defined the props.)

Comment: AFAIK you can't control the precision of the property , and this solution is for printing/displaying only , where exactly this is bothering you ?

Comment: I am just trying to make a smaller property and I dont want to write an interval from (e.g.) 0 - 0.499999999999999..., It would be much simpler to have 0 - 0.4.

Comment: sorry but i don't get exactly your last comment ( give me another example )

Comment: Well, I have events that work when a property is at a certain interval. If one interval is 0 - 0.4, the next one is 0.5 - 1. I do not want to have 0.499999999999999999... Do you understand now?

Comment: so you are doing a comparison, you can round the number before comparing like this `round(myProp, 1) < 0.4` or simply `myProp <0.5` istead

Comment: Well, I'm using logic bricks, and if I round, lets say, 0 - 0.4 & and 0.5 - 1, **there will be no outcome for 0.4000001, 0.400001, etc.**

Comment: to me it seems that both case can be done like  this (  `prop  Greater_than 0.0  and prop Less_than 0.5`  the second `prop  Greater_than 0.5  and prop Less_than 1.0` )

Comment: It seems to me that you are using the property sensor to check if a certain property is equal to an exact value, am I correct?

Comment: I got it to work though, I've used your approach. Thanks!